# computehash same for 2 different files

Tags: c#

I am trying to use ComputeHash to determine if a server file and client file are the same. The files in question could be a few megs or could be 80 megs. I have seen this work fine on smaller files, but now I am trying to do files that are a few megs and I am getting back the same hash string for different files(vastly different files).

My procedure is something like this:

```
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
//SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();
byte[] checksum = md5.ComputeHash(remoteClip.bytes);
string crc = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
```

As you can see in the sample I have tried both MD5 and SHA1Managed and they provide different results, but the same result on each file. I verified the byte array is not the same that is given in to each call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Verify again? One of your assumptions is incorrect.

Comment: Can you verify that `remoteClip.bytes` actually changes?

Comment: Wow Just Wow... Visual studios was just lieing to me on the mouse over variable inspection popup. I went to take screenshots to show what the values are and I noticed the locals window at the bottom shows the correct values. Sorry false alarm here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out visual studios was showing me bogus values on mouseover inspection and the crcs were not the same. It just wasn't updating on subsequent itterations.

Comment: It would probibly be better to just delete your question